# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'send_keys' error using Excel sheet to get the data through Selenium and Python

Tags: python, list, selenium, selenium-webdriver, attributeerror

This a program of Data driven testing, where email id and password is taking from Excel sheet. But I am not to able get the data from excel sheet getting an error. I have already attached the screenshot.

Code trial:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import openpyxl
import XLUtilities
import time

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users/sonu.j.kumar/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/account/login?ret=/")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
path="C://Users/sonu.j.kumar/PycharmProjects/Login_Credentials.xlsx"

wb=openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
sheet=wb["Sheet1"]

user_name=(sheet['A2'].value)
print(user_name)
pwd=(sheet['B2'].value)
print(pwd)

driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@autocomplete='off'][@class='_2zrpKA _1dBPDZ']").send_keys(user_name)
driver.find_elements_by_class_name("_2zrpKA _3v41xv _1dBPDZ").send_keys(pwd)
```

Comment: I got the solution, I just removed th "s" from elements in " find_element_by_xpath" and it starts working.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
```

...implies that your program have attempted to invoke `send_keys()` method on a *List* element.

---

### send_keys(*value)

[`send_keys(*value)`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.send_keys) simulates typing into the element.

So `send_keys()` is a [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) method and can't be invoked on a *List*.

---

### Solution

Instead of `find_elements_by_xpath()` and `find_elements_by_class_name()` you need to use `find_element_by_xpath()` and `find_element_by_class_name()`. Effectively your line of code will be:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@autocomplete='off'][@class='_2zrpKA _1dBPDZ']").send_keys(user_name)
driver.find_element_by_class_name("_2zrpKA _3v41xv _1dBPDZ").send_keys(pwd)
```